# win32 waiting for events(synchroniztion)

Tags: winapi, events, synchronization

I have 3 windows that have to interact with each other using events.
windows 1 and 2 are identical; each only have one button in them.

Basically, I the main window(program 3) to not show up until **one** of the other two windows buttons
is clicked; this is how it was describes in the lab:

You need to use synchronization to control the processes (starting Program3 via Program1 or 2, ending Program1 or 2 via closing Program3). Note: Program1 and Program2 must have had their button clicked in order for them to receive the signal to die

I've been looking around and got this so far for code:

**Main window(program 3):**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<string.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
     static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("RACE") ;
     HWND         hwnd ;
     MSG          msg ;
     WNDCLASS     wndclass ;
     HANDLE hEvents[2];
     hEvents[0] = "btn2";
     hEvents[1] = "btn3";
     DWORD count = 2;

     HBRUSH brush;
     brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));

     wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
     wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
     wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
     wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
     wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
     wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
     wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
     wndclass.hbrBackground = brush;
     wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
     wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

     if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
     {
          MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"), 
                      szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
          return 0 ;
     }
     TCHAR* name;

     //WAIT FOR SIGNAL
     DWORD result = WaitForMultipleObjects(count,hEvents,FALSE,INFINITE);//work on this
     if(result == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
     {
        name = TEXT("Program 1");       
     }
     else if(result == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
     {
        name = TEXT("Program 2");
     }

    hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,                  // window class name
                          name, // window caption
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                          0,              // initial x position
                          0,              // initial y position
                          600,              // initial x size
                          600,              // initial y size
                          NULL,                       // parent window handle
                          NULL,                       // window menu handle
                          hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                          NULL);                     // creation parameters



     ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;//DON'T SHOW UNTIL ANOTHER WINDOW'S BUTTON IS PUSHED.
     UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
     {
          TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
          DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
     }
     return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     HDC         hdc ;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps ;


     TCHAR* carNames[5] = {TEXT("Red Car"), TEXT("Blue Car"), TEXT("Black Car"), TEXT("Green Car"), TEXT("Orange Car")};
     switch (message)
     {
     case WM_CREATE:
         HWND hwndButton;

         for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
         hwndButton = CreateWindow ( TEXT("button"),//type of child window 
                                   carNames[i],//text displayed on button
                                   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,//type of button
                                   20, (20*i*5+10),
                                   85, 25,
                                   hwnd, //parent handle i.e. main window handle
                                    (HMENU) i,//child ID – any number
                                   ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
         }



         break;


          return 0 ;

     case WM_PAINT:
          hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;



          EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
          return 0 ;

    /* case WM_CLOSE:

          c--;
          DestroyWindow(hwnd);
          return 0 ;*/

     case WM_DESTROY:

          PostQuitMessage (0) ;
          return 0 ;
     }
     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

**window 2(program2):**

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

    int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                        PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
    {
         static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("Part 2") ;
         HWND         hwnd ;
         MSG          msg ;
         WNDCLASS     wndclass ;


         wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
         wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
         wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
         wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
         wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
         wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
         wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
         wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
         wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
         wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

         if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
         {
              MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"), 
                          szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
              return 0 ;
         }

         hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,                  // window class name
                              TEXT ("Part 2"), // window caption
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                              0,              // initial x position
                              0,              // initial y position
                              300,              // initial x size
                              200,              // initial y size
                              NULL,                       // parent window handle
                              NULL,                       // window menu handle
                              hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                             NULL) ;                     // creation parameters



         ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
         UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;


         while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
         {
              TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
              DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
         }
         return msg.wParam ;
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
         HDC         hdc ;
         PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
         HANDLE hEvent;


         switch (message)
         {
         case WM_CREATE:
             HWND hwndButton2;
               hwndButton2 = CreateWindow ( TEXT("button"),//type of child window 
                                       TEXT("PRESS ME!"),//text displayed on button
                                       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,//type of button
                                       20, 20,
                                       200, 25,
                                       hwnd, //parent handle i.e. main window handle
                                        (HMENU) 45,//child ID – any number
                                       ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

               hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, //no security attributes
                FALSE, //auto-reset event object
                FALSE, //initial state is nonsignaled
                L"btn2"); //unnamed object



              return 0 ;

         case WM_PAINT:
              hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;



              EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
              return 0 ;

         case WM_COMMAND:


             SetEvent("btn2");

             return 0;

         case WM_DESTROY:

              PostQuitMessage (0) ;
              return 0 ;
         }
         return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
    }
```

and **window 3 (program 3):** which is pretty much identical to window 2

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<string.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
     static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("Part 3") ;
     HWND         hwnd ;
     MSG          msg ;
     WNDCLASS     wndclass ;


     wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
     wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
     wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
     wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
     wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
     wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
     wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
     wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
     wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
     wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

     if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
     {
          MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"), 
                      szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
          return 0 ;
     }

     hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,                  // window class name
                          TEXT ("Part 3"), // window caption
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                          0,              // initial x position
                          0,              // initial y position
                          300,              // initial x size
                          200,              // initial y size
                          NULL,                       // parent window handle
                          NULL,                       // window menu handle
                          hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                         NULL) ;                     // creation parameters



     ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
     UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;


     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
     {
          TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
          DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
     }
     return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     HDC         hdc ;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
     HANDLE hEvent1;

     switch (message)
     {
     case WM_CREATE:
           HWND hwndButton3;
           hwndButton3 = CreateWindow ( TEXT("button"),//type of child window 
                                   TEXT("PRESS ME!"),//text displayed on button
                                   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,//type of button
                                   20, 20,
                                   200, 25,
                                   hwnd, //parent handle i.e. main window handle
                                    (HMENU) 95,//child ID – any number
                                   ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

           hEvent1 = CreateEvent(NULL, //no security attributes
            FALSE, //auto-reset event object
            FALSE, //initial state is nonsignaled
            L"btn3"); //unnamed object


          return 0 ;

     case WM_PAINT:
          hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;



          EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
          return 0 ;

          case WM_COMMAND:

         SetEvent("btn3");

         return 0;


     case WM_DESTROY:

          PostQuitMessage (0) ;
          return 0 ;
     }
     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

These are all in the same solution; but in different projects(multiple project in one solution).

The problem right now is that I can't seem to get the main window to open when I click 
either one of the buttons. I've tried many different things, but none seem to be working.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Your first prog has no WM_COMMAND handler for processing child control/menu commands. (2) Your second prog is almost as blank, but does include an invalid `SetEvent()` call using a string constant rather than a valid event-handle. Your third is effectively a duplicate of the second, only difference being a different invalid SetEvent() call using a different (and in incorrect) string constant. In short, aside from adding a dozen lines of code to the stock WIN32-wizard generated project files, this is nowhere *close* to the task your assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 HANDLE hEvents[2];
 hEvents[0] = "btn2";
 hEvents[1] = "btn3";
```

That's not right.  You'll have to call the `CreateEvent` function just like you do in the other two programs.

Comment: I'm creating the events in the other two window programs. I was told that I make them there and then when the button is clicked, to set the event with SetEvent. And that the name given to the event would be how to identify it when waiting for the event(WaitForMultipleObjects).

so I would think that I have to put those specific events into the handle array. But I couldn't figure out how to do that.
wouldn't creating a new event be a different event than the one I need?

Comment: I beleive your are confusing *real world* events like clicking on a button with a physical mouse on a physical desk, and synchronization primitives.

Comment: @LuciferFayte: Read the documentation for how named events work.  Using the same name will create a new handle to the existing event.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you.
You are right; creating an event that has the same name as an already existing event will return the handle to you. As far as I understand it.

Comment: You can also use `OpenEvent`, but only if you know the other program already created the event.  If both run at the same time, better to use `CreateEvent` twice.